# How can I reimplement jQuery-style chaining in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

One of the conveniences offered by JavaScript's [jQuery](https://jquery.com) is the ability to [chain methods](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/what-is-chaining-in-jquery.html) like so:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dvContent')
        .addClass('dummy')
        .css('color', 'red')
        .fadeIn('slow');
});​
```

Instead of the more verbose non-chained way of writing the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dvContent').addClass('dummy');
    $('#dvContent').css('color', 'red');
    $('#dvContent').fadeIn('slow');
});​
```

*Above jQuery code courtesy of [jquerybyexample.net](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/what-is-chaining-in-jquery.html).*

This is possible because the `$(selector)` function in jQuery returns a jQuery reference to whatever is indicated by `selector`, and it is standard for jQuery functions that don't return some type of value (i.e. would otherwise be `void`) to return the jQuery reference from `$(selector)` so that the next function in the chain can make use of it.

**In Rust, however, this seems impossible.**

Let's implement this in pseudo-Rust:

```
fn $(selector: &Selector) -> JQueryReference {
    JQuery::get(selector)
}
```

So far so good...

```
impl Chainable for JQueryReference {
    fn addClass(&self, class: String) -> Self {
        deep_frontendy_stuff_add_class(&self, class);
        self
    }
}
```

Ooh, no bueno, that `deep_frontendy_stuff_add_class()` function can't modify `self`. Oh I know, I'll just make the reference mutable!

```
impl Chainable for JQueryReference {
    fn addClass(&mut self, class: String) -> Self {
        deep_frontendy_stuff_add_class(&mut self, class);
        self
    }
}
```

Cool, that worked! But wait, what if I want to go old school and not use the fancy chained types?

```
$("#dvContent".to_string()).addClass("dummy".to_string());
$("#dvContent".to_string()).css("color".to_string(), "red".to_string());
```

Nooooooooo! The borrow checker is at it again!

How do I implement such behavior, and if you wouldn't mind, please be as descriptive as possible about *why*. This question is really an example to help understand the language.

Comment: *The borrow checker is at it again!* — how? there are no errors in this question.

Comment: Have you already read [How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617182/155423) and [How to use the chained builder pattern in a loop without creating a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45517265/155423)

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Your "pseudo-Rust" doesn't need to be and actively makes it *harder* for us to see what the problem is. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an idiomatic build pattern with chained method calls in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41617182/608639)

Comment: @Shepmaster My apologies for the lack of clarity, as I said at the end of the question (and as I probably should have said at the start), the emphasis isn't on the chained calls at all, it's on the borrow checker, and basically understanding how code can be written that is both borrow-checker-friendly and effective, as sometimes it feels like the borrow checker disallows every possible solution to a problem